# PNG size growth when using RenderTargetBitmap and PngBitmapEncoder

Tags: c#, wpf, png, imaging, tiling

I'm using a method to merge some tile images into a single image. But if I apply it to four 30kb- PNG images, the resulting PNG image would be 500K (~4x more than what I expect)

This is some part of the code that I'm using (*suggested by Cédric Bignon*):

```
BitmapFrame frame1 = BitmapDecoder.Create(new Uri(path1), BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad).Frames.First();
BitmapFrame frame2 = BitmapDecoder.Create(new Uri(path2), BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad).Frames.First();
BitmapFrame frame3 = BitmapDecoder.Create(new Uri(path3), BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad).Frames.First();
BitmapFrame frame4 = BitmapDecoder.Create(new Uri(path4), BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad).Frames.First();

// Gets the size of the images (I assume each image has the same size)
int imageWidth = frame1.PixelWidth;
int imageHeight = frame1.PixelHeight;

// Draws the images into a DrawingVisual component
DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
using (DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
{
    drawingContext.DrawImage(frame1, new Rect(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight));
    drawingContext.DrawImage(frame2, new Rect(imageWidth, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight));
    drawingContext.DrawImage(frame3, new Rect(0, imageHeight, imageWidth, imageHeight));
    drawingContext.DrawImage(frame4, new Rect(imageWidth, imageHeight, imageWidth, imageHeight));
}

// Converts the Visual (DrawingVisual) into a BitmapSource
RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(imageWidth * 2, imageHeight * 2, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
bmp.Render(drawingVisual);

// Creates a PngBitmapEncoder and adds the BitmapSource to the frames of the encoder
PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));

// Saves the image into a file using the encoder
using (Stream stream = File.OpenWrite(pathTileImage))
    encoder.Save(stream);
```

Anyone knows what is going on?

Comment: What is the exact size in pixels of the result image?

Comment: Small images are 256*256 and the big image is 512*512

Comment: It's possible, tile images is compressed, but result image is not.

Comment: @Memoizer can you explain more? thanks.

Comment: PNG format supports compression: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Compression Maybe, tile image is compressed (this explains the small size)

Comment: @Memoizer How can I compress the combined image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to say without knowing the original images. PNG supports several color models and compressions. If, for example, the 4 original images have (different) palettes, and the composition will have to resort to a true colour format, and the total size will probably be way more than 4 times the original sizes.

Comment: Original images are the same (same= palettes, ...)

Comment: Both 4 subimages are the same? Are they paletted? Did you check whether the result is palletted or true-color?

Comment: Your edit didn't answer my questions. It's not even clear if your assertion "original images are the same" means that they are of the same "type", or if they are identical.

Comment: First: "Original images are the same (same= palettes, ...)"  Then: "somehow the same source(???).... not paletted"  Well, you don't make things easy for us. You'd better attach the images.

Comment: Sorry! I used `JpegBitmapEncoder` insted of `PngBitmapEncoder` and the resulting image was 126kb. So I checked original images again. In windows properties it is written `Item type: PNG Image` and `Bit Depth : 24`. When I ran the code in the `CodecInfo` of the frames it was written `FriendlyName = JPEG Decoder`. So I think my previous assumption (which was based on Windows properties) was wrong. Original images are not PNG. Am I correct?